# How to update createControls's function input variables at javascript?

Tags: javascript, resize, three.js, controls

I have a

```
 function createControls(){ return new THREE.TrackballControls( camera,domElement );}
```

which is created with

```
THREE.TrackballControls=function(object, domElement){.....}
controls = createControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
restoreView(controls, vars);
addDefaultKeyEventListener();
```

and after resizing the webgl container the controls dont work correct..to be precise there is an event where when the user clicks on the screen a yellow ball moves to the exact place on a plain at the 3d space. After the resize event the ball moves at a spot which has a offset of that place i suppose related with the resized scale. When i try to redefine controls variable it crashes..

How can i update the controls having new camera and renderer.domElement input variables?

Comment: also as i see the problem is that the renderer.setSize is changing as the browser window is resized. if i keep the same size it causes distortion to the content. Any help how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TrackballControls` have a method for that : `handleResize()`. So if you create your controls with

```
controls=new THREE.TrackballControls(...);
```

You just have to add

```
controls.handleResize();
```

into the function called at the `resize` event.