# How to update Trackball controls at three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, controls, trackball

I have a project at three.js where i need to update the trackball controls on window resize.. I need to do that updating the whole controls calling the function with new input variables. Recreating the controls causes crash and i dont want to delete the controls and create new one cause of the garbage this might cause. I have a similar question [How to update createControls's function input variables at javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577347/how-to-update-createcontrolss-function-input-variables-at-javascript) but i think this is more complete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update `TrackballControls` when you resize the window, you can use this pattern:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    controls.handleResize(); // for TrackballControls

    render();

}
```

You will have to modify this pattern depending on how your canvas is sized.

See http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html.

three.js r.70

Comment: sorry for the late reply! I was searching to solve my problem but with no result. What i need is to update the trackball controls to detect the mouse position event to a different screen. I managed to make the handleResize() function but the getmousePosition(event) is not working correct. any help how to fix this?

Comment: When you have a new question, you need to make a new post.